# Strategies for lengthy answers and questions (like this one)

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

#### Concerning answers

**TL;DR what** : It would be interesting to have a template/format/guidelines for presenting lengthy answers.

**TL;DR why** : To increase the general quality of answers, to guide newcomers and to avoid interesting information being diluted in lengthy text.

From my tiny database of answers I have read, my impression is that the answers at the top tend to be those that have the least amount of code or text. This is not true for some of the legendary answers typically from 2012 but it seems to be particularly true as the site looses activity over the years (I read the meta post about how the site is becoming less active).

That is probably quite natural. I myself upvote these sorts of questions quickly but I am more hesitant with long answers as it is harder to evaluate the value or because of my bias that short means better. However, the criteria of a good answer probably extends beyond the length of code. Some possible criteria are:

- Generalizability (not a word ?)
- Usage of rarely used functions
- Robustness
- Clarity of the exposition
- Speed
- Useful general knowledge

In an ideal world, AI would scan through the answers and evaluate scores for these points regardless of the length of the answer. In the real world we are probably going to get a vague look at the answer and upvote based on the length of the answer, usage of a rare function and an undocumented explanation of a function.

That's human nature and we can not expect anymore from voters. The question is then what should/can we do for/about the answers.

As an example a lengthy code that uses mathematica's new compiler and uses an algorithm from a recent paper might not get that much attention compared to a one line answer that uses `Tuples` and tries all possible cases.

Basically I feel like ideally there should be a user guide "How to present a lengthy answer" with maybe a notice "but try to keep it short ok"

### Concerning Questions

Ideally I think there should be some sort of template for questions like on Github when posting an issue.

A template would probably make questions both shorter and more clear thus avoiding the large number of closed posts, time consumed by users and general quality of questions.

It is mainly a suggestion that one can provide to the person asking the question not a rule. That seems to me particularly important before closing questions as some do not understand why their votes were closed or downvoted.

Comment: I am hesitating on whether I should include a first draft for possible templates in my question. I am not sure if that is seen as "OP made effort into starting the discussion by providing ideas" or "OP should should ask a question and leave other  members provide better solutions"

Comment: Hello thank you for the advice. I should have made more explicit points. I think the problems are in the original post but diluted in all the words. I will change it thank you.

Comment: @rhermans I edited the post. Basically questions and answers might get ignored by their length but they might be interesting. A suggested template might make it easier to get the gist of a question or answer. The template might also explain why a question was closed as I would imagine it often happens that someone just does not understand why their question was closed which hurts and makes it more likely that they will avoid the site.

Comment: Following up on what you said about a curated Q&A the current method is like a MonteCarlo method where one just waits until some answers and questions fit into the mold of what is expected and we take the best with a few not so good in the mix. Instead with a template there is a directed force/push towards quality and clarity.

Comment: You assume that there will be a "one fits all" template that works for all posible Q&A, I'm not sure that is the case.

Comment: @rhermans no there is not a one size fits all. Like most forms that one fills there is category list and then "other". One can always choose other and accept the risk that that might imply less attention. The  keyword I tried to place was the word suggestion.

Comment: BTW, I do appreciate your enthusiasm and willingness to re-think the site to improve it. That is a good thing. However, please understand that we have limited power to influence how people behave, and however many failures you can see in this site, it works better than most other similar sites. That said, the excursive you propose may yield a good guide. Let's see.

Comment: @rhermans agreed the site has been quite helpful to me through the years.

Comment: @rhermans and yes I am quite aware that human behavior can not be adjusted in a large group. I tried making a facebook group to share information after a natural disaster occurred in my hometown and I noticed then that the inertia in human behavior is significant even in times of need. The template as a suggestion would most likely be a mild increase in quality of posts but might maybe lead to a group behavior of adopting a template style.